# Django - how to set user create article is by user is logon

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin, django-users

```
class Article(models.Model):
    slidenumber = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.CharField(default='', max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    timeupdate = models.DateTimeField('Date Published')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, default=1)
```

If I set author field has default=1, when I login django admin page to create a article it will alway get author is my superuser (has ID =1), so How I can set if I login admin django page to create article by other user(not my superuser), the author field will get user is logon current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know where did you create Article in admin page or in view.

1. If you create article in django-admin just rewrite `.save()` method and set author.

This code will work:

```
class Article(admin.ModelAdmin):
  def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
     obj.author = request.user
     super(Article, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

2. If you create article in view just rewrite `post()` method logic and set author as above

Comment: ```    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.author = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change) ```

Answer (score 0):

The default value for the logged used can be achieved by

---

`{{request.user}}`

---

This returns the currently logged-on user.
In your views, create a default value with a function like this

```
def get_initial():      
    return {request.user}
```

When creating the form,

```
user=forms.ModelChoiceField(
    widget=forms.HiddenInput,
    queryset=get_user_model().objects.all(),        
    disabled=True,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.author = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

It work fine.